# Angular4 - changing css class dynamically - which is better?

Tags: angular

From the tutorial, instructor came up with this:

```
<span class="glyphicon" [class.glyphicon-star-empty]="isFavorite" [class.glyphicon-star]="!isFavorite" (click)="toggleClass()"></span>
```

Component:

```
isFavorite = false;

toggleClass() {
 this.isFavorite != this.isFavorite;
}
```

---

While my way was:

```
<span class="glyphicon" [ngClass]="classes" (click)="toggleClasses()"></span>
```

Component:

```
classes = "glyphicon-star-empty";

toggleClasses() {
 this.classes == "glyphicon-star-empty"? this.classes = "glyphicon-star" : this.classes = "glyphicon-star-empty";
}
```

Both ways works as expected, but I feel my way is not very good from performance perspective because I am using a loop, right?

Sorry if answer might be simply "yes". I just want to be sure about how this works (especially interested in all those Ng directives, like ngModel, ngClass).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is of course very subjective, but if you're worried about performance, then in this particular case probably the first one will work faster because the compiler will create the following streamlined function to set the classes:

```
   function updateRenderer() {
        var _co = _v.component;
        var currVal_0 = _co.isFavorite;
        var currVal_1 = _co.isFavorite;
        _ck(_v, 0, 0, currVal_1, currVal_1);
        ...
    });
```

and `_ck` function will eventually call `renderer.setElementClass` for each class. To learn more about `updateRenderer` function read [The mechanics of DOM updates in Angular](https://hackernoon.com/the-mechanics-of-dom-updates-in-angular-3b2970d5c03d), particularly `Update renderer` section.

While the `ngClass` goes through the time consuming process of checking the changes using differs:

```
  ngDoCheck(): void {
    if (this._iterableDiffer) {
      const iterableChanges = this._iterableDiffer.diff(this._rawClass as string[]);
      if (iterableChanges) {
        this._applyIterableChanges(iterableChanges);
      }
    } else if (this._keyValueDiffer) {
      const keyValueChanges = this._keyValueDiffer.diff(this._rawClass as{[k: string]: any});
      if (keyValueChanges) {
        this._applyKeyValueChanges(keyValueChanges);
      }
    }
  }
```

However, the `ngClass` has much richer functionality so it's not fair to compare their performance.

Answer (score 12):

Best way is to write it this way.

```
[ngClass]="{'class1': isFavorite, 'class2': !isFavorite}"
```

Like

```
<span class="glyphicon" [ngClass]="{'class1': isFavorite, 'class2': !isFavorite}" (click)="toggleClass()"></span>
```

Then you can bind toggleHandler

```
toggleClass() {
 this.isFavorite != this.isFavorite;
}
```

Comment: Can you add a demo please?